# Outlook macro not writing to shared mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook, rules

The following macro creates an Outlook rule correctly, but only in my private email account, not in the shared mailbox I am targeting. Can someone please identify any errors/omissions in the code that are causing it not to link to the shared mailbox?

```
Sub CreateRule_MSmodified5()
'Creates rule in private folder, not shared mailbox

Dim sharedMailboxName As String
sharedMailboxName = "sharedmailbox@abcxyz.zz"

Dim olApp As Object
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Set olRecipient = olNamespace.CreateRecipient(sharedMailboxName)
olRecipient.Resolve

Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder
If olRecipient.Resolved Then
    Set oInbox = olNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecipient, olFolderInbox)
End If

Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder
Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Test")

Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules
Set colRules = olNamespace.DefaultStore.GetRules()
Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule
Set oRule = colRules.Create("C5", olRuleReceive)
  
Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction
Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
With oMoveRuleAction
    .Enabled = True
    .Folder = oMoveTarget
End With

Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition
Set oExceptSubject = oRule.Exceptions.Subject
With oExceptSubject
    .Enabled = True
    .Text = Array("string1", "string2")
End With

colRules.Save

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether saving to another store is feasible, "technically" you need the non-default store.

It could look like this.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateRule_MSmodified5_nondefaultStore()

Dim sharedMailboxName As String
sharedMailboxName = "sharedmailbox@abcxyz.zz"

Dim olNamespace As namespace
Set olNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")

Dim olRecipient As Recipient
Set olRecipient = olNamespace.CreateRecipient(sharedMailboxName)
olRecipient.Resolve

Dim oInbox As folder
'Email address is always resolved. Use when not an email address.
If olRecipient.Resolved Then   
    Set oInbox = olNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(olRecipient, olFolderInbox)
End If

Dim oMoveTarget As folder
Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Test")

Dim colRules As Rules

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Session.Stores.count

    Debug.Print Session.Stores(i)
    
    If Session.Stores(i) = sharedMailboxName Then

        Set colRules = Session.Stores(i).GetRules()
        
        Dim oRule As Rule
        Set oRule = colRules.Create("C5", olRuleReceive)
          
        Dim oMoveRuleAction As MoveOrCopyRuleAction
        Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder
        With oMoveRuleAction
            .Enabled = True
            .folder = oMoveTarget
        End With
        
        Dim oExceptSubject As TextRuleCondition
        Set oExceptSubject = oRule.Exceptions.subject
        With oExceptSubject
            .Enabled = True
            .Text = Array("string1", "string2")
        End With
        
        colRules.Save
        
        Exit For
        
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Server side Exchange rules can only target folders in the same store (mailbox). Remember that your rule runs on the server, and it might not have access to the target folder in another mailbox.